# Fail to start linux container after upgrading to docker 1.5

Tags: linux, docker, containers, lxc

I used to use docker 1.3 and it worked well. There're some problems after upgrading to docker 1.5. Is there something about my lxc? And I have tried `apt-get purge lxc` and `apt-get install lxc` to re-install it.

```
➜  ~  sudo docker version
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.4.1
Git commit (client): a8a31ef
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.5.0
Server API version: 1.17
Go version (server): go1.4.1
Git commit (server): a8a31ef
➜  ~  sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu:14.10 /bin/bash
lxc-start: No such file or directory - failed to use 'proc sys'
lxc-start: failed to setup the mounts for 'b4f70ce8559154b65c80e48d3002ab804d9b00a952ae8efb7803d6251c865b16'
lxc-start: failed to setup the container
lxc-start: invalid sequence number 1. expected 2
lxc-start: failed to spawn 'b4f70ce8559154b65c80e48d3002ab804d9b00a952ae8efb7803d6251c865b16'
➜  ~  lxc-version
lxc version: 1.0.0.alpha1
```

And lxc seems work well to start.

```
➜  temp  sudo lxc-create -n test-container -t ubuntu
➜  temp  sudo lxc-ls --fancy
NAME            STATE    IPV4  IPV6  AUTOSTART  
----------------------------------------------
test-container  STOPPED  -     -     NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching from lxc to native exec drivers in docker. You can do this by adding --exec-driver="native" to DOCKER_OPTS  in config file ( /etc/default/docker). Native exec driver has now best support in docker and its used as default on most installations.

Comment: While this works, this is not a solution to the actual problem, you're just sidestepping it.

Comment: Anyway, it works for my development environment and thanks @Sec.

Comment: True, it's a workaround. But I already encountered this type of problem few times. And it always was incompatibility between docker and lxc tools. This was one of reasons for switching to in house maintained exec driver in Docker project.